# Apache server-status when running as proxy server

Tags: proxy, apache-1.3

We are running apache as a proxy server and have tomcat behind apache. We are using server_status module but when we try to access server_status as in `https://host.com/server-status` it redirects to tomcat and we get 404 error. 
I am quite new to this, tried going through apache docs but unable to figure out the solution. Fyi.We have ssl enabled

Current ssl.conf settings:

```
  ProxyRequests     Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy http://localhost:8081/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse   /  http://myhost:8081/


    <Location /server-status>
            SetHandler server-status
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 10.90
    </Location>
```

After suggested changes

```
 ProxyRequests     Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy http://localhost:8081/*>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass         /server-status !
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse   /  http://myhost:8081/
```

Edit 2:

Change was required to httpd.conf and I added the  `ProxyPass  /server-status !` under the directive for proxy module configuration and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `!` in the ProxyPass directive for proxy exceptions. Something like

```
ProxyPass /server-status !
```

ought to do it.

See apache docs for ProxyPass directive for more: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass , especially

> The ! directive is useful in situations where you don't want to
>   reverse-proxy a subdirectory, e.g.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working from me. This should be the ideal solution but it isnt.

Comment: It could be the order of things. Update your question with the new configs.

Comment: Updated the question with the new config

Comment: Place it after the  `</Location>` line and restart the web server

Comment: I was updating ssl.conf and seems like httpd.conf was supposed to be updated with your suggestion. But, its working now. Thank you KM

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of sites and some of them had 'Redirect permanent' in it. 
For some reason it doesn't work (at least for me).

I use the /server-status for monitoring so I only had to connect to it from another server inside the local LAN. So I created an extra Vhost with the local IP as the ServerName like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName   <<local_server_ip>>
   ServerAlias  <<local_server_ip>>
   ServerAdmin  foo@example.com

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not an expert but it worked for me.